# Angular element directive how to get attribute value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using an Angular element directive to generate an amount of stars (rating) for a given item.

I create a directive called 'generateStars' and I am using it like so in the view.

```
<generate-stars amount="3"></generate-stars>
```

I don't want the directive to be dependant on the current scope so I was wondering if I could take in the "amount" attribute and get the value within my directive function.

Here is that function:

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])

.directive('generateStars', function() {
    var html = '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: html,
        replace: true
    };
});
```

I couldn't find any obvious documentation to allow me to get the value of 'amount' inside my directive function.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use isolated scope and use `amount` value can be passed as attribute as you are doing so.

**Markup**

```
<generate-stars amount="{{amount}}"></generate-stars>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.amount = 3; //passing it through the scope.
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])

.directive('generateStars', function() {
    var html = '<i ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" class="fa fa-star" ng-if="i>=amount"></i>';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: html,
        replace: true,
        scope: { 
           amount: '@' //`@` for one way binding.
        }
    };
});
```

This can be without isolated scope. Basically you need to create class `fa-3x` in your directive template.

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])

.directive('generateStars', function() {
        return '<i ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" class="fa fa-star" ng-if="i>='+ attrs.amount +' "></i>'
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: html,
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Comment: `fa-3x` is for font-size, not for amount of icons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This code sample doesn't allow me to take in the value given from the HTML element and use it within my directive. I would like to avoid using 'scope' altogether. I just want to take the value in from the HTML attribute in the custom directive element.

Comment: @Dan did you tried the second example which I;ve added in answer..it plays with `attribute` only..without considering scope

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attrs` object available in your `link` function of your Directive Definition Object.

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])
.directive('generateStars', function() {
    var html = '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: html,
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           /*all attributes passed to directive are available as properties
              on attrs object*/
            console.log(attrs.amount);
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<generate-stars amount="3"></generate-stars>
```

With that, when your directive is rendered, prints the value 3 in console.

Comment: I'm trying to use the "amount" variable inside the directive before the return statement. In this case I need to know that the amount is equal to 3 and then generate 3 HTML elements to return.

Comment: I think you're confused by the return statement. You're basically returning a definition object while registering your custom directive with angular.  It's `link` function is called before translating your custom directive code to your html (referred by `template`) in the browser

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help guys but neither of these solutions ended up working out for me. This is what I ended up doing.

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])

.directive('generateStars', function() {
    var html = '<i class="fa fa-star" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:roundedAmount"></i>';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            amount: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.roundedAmount = parseInt(scope.amount);
        },
        replace: true,
        template: html
    };
})

.filter('range', function() {
    return function(input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total);
        for (var i=0; i<total; i++)
            input.push(i);

        return input;
    };
});
```